# How to escape XML's special characters from php exec

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

*I usually manage to find by myself the answers of my questions by searching on internet, but for this problem I don't have any idea anymore...*

I am adding content to an XML file (which is several Go) via php exec command.
*I must do it this way because I need to have an XML to import data in my Solr Collection*

```
<?php
$cmd = "echo '\b' > /windowsShare/solr_update_20150728.xml";
var_dump($cmd);
//exec($cmd);
passthru($cmd);
```

The strange behavior is that if I "manually" run the output, my XML is valid...
But somehow, when I execute it via php, it's inserting some special characters (invalid ones).

e.g.: \b insert a "BS" on a black blackground (in Notepad++)

I already tried:
    htmlspecialchars (addSlashes('\b'), ENT_XML1)

Please, help :)

---

EDIT: simply add a "\" is a solution for this specific '\b' character, but I would like to have a general solution:

E.g.: $txt = "(\b €.......or d≥3";

is displayed like that in Notepad++:

(\b â¬.......or dâ¥3

NOTE: I have the feeling that this is an encoding problem... (it's well displayed when I changed the encoding to UTF8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my edit, this was an encoding problem. 
I was inserting '< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>' to the XML.

So the SQL data (UTF-8) was converting to another format.
Now, I insert < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>.

And both the XML and the SQL data are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add literal `\` and `b` characters to your xml? Since you're using `"`-quoted strings, `\b` is treated as a backspace. you'd have to double-escape:

```
$cmd = "echo '\\b' > /windowsShare/solr_update_20150728.xml";
              ^^
```

You could switch to using a `'`-quoted string, where `\b` has no special meaning, but then you have to escape the echo quotes as well:

```
$cmd = 'echo \'\b\' > /windowsShare/solr_update_20150728.xml';
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for a general function (like htmlspecialchars for example) which could do this but I can simply replace '\' by '\\'. solution is: str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $mystring)

Comment: Actually, this fixed the case of this specific char ('\b'), but still not a general solution...I edited my question

Comment: then try `addslashes()`